# no difference between local branches but remote pull request shows over 100 files changed

Tags: git, github, merge, pull-request

Branches `develop` and `master` are up to date with remote (`ran git fetch && git pull`). When I run `git diff master..develop` no differences are shown between branches.

However, when I create a pull request from develop into master on github it shows 139 changed files! The changes are substantial changes to the code.

[image]

Github also states *This branch is 10 commits ahead, 19 commits behind develop.* when viewing master branch.

Can anyone help me understand why this might be and how to resolve?

Comment: What kind of changes are shown in that pull request? Actual changes, or could it just be line-ending differences?

Comment: The changes are actually changes to the code.